# Ошибка: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, list

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a = input()
print(a.splitlines(';'))
```

n - количество сток. Ввожу в переменную а - Спартак;9;Зенит;10. Должно выводить ['Спартак', 9, 'Зенит', 10], но выводит ошибку. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Будет ``['Спартак', '9', 'Зенит', '10']``, а не ``['Спартак', 9, 'Зенит', 10]`` (см. кавычки вокруг чисел).

Comment: У вас вообще странный цикл - на каждой итерации получаете ввод и перетираете предыдущее значение переменной, не используя его никак. А если это просто заготовка, то тем более зачем нам знать про цикл? )

Answer (score 4):

`a.split(';')` а не `a.splitlines(';')` :

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    a = input()
print(a.split(';'))
```